# Django One-Click Install Image on Digital Ocean

Tags: python, django, deployment, gunicorn, digital-ocean

So i am trying to follow this tutorial about [How To Use the Django One-Click Install Image](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image?utm_source=Customerio&utm_medium=Email_Internal&utm_campaign=Email_DjangoWelcome) to deploy my Django 1.7 project in a Digital Ocean Droplet but i am running into some problems.

Basically if i do `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000` everything works fine, but when trying to use it with `Gunicorn` i get a

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not
>   configured. You must either define the environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing
>   settings.

my `gunicorn.conf` is:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=bla \
    --pythonpath=bla \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    bla_api.wsgi:application
```

my `wsgi` is:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bla_api.settings.production")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any ideas?? i tried export `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bla_api.settings.production` with no luck

Comment: I did the Ruby on Rails one-click install and ended up de-constructing and re-configuring from scratch--to plug in all the missing components from the one-click. I'm not saying this an answer, only saying I'm not surprised that the one-click install may not work as advertised.

Comment: @ValerieAsensio i did the same, re-configured almost everything, so so much for "one click install"